# XQuery - Swap attribute and element values (inverse structure) dynamically

Tags: sql, xml, attributes, xquery, element

So I have this (unusual) task

> "Write a query that inverts all the sub elements of the /music element
>   so that their own sub elements become attributes and their attributes
>   become sub elements. For those sub elements that lack sub elements of
>   their own, their data content should become an attribute with the name
>   'value'."

where I use this database: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Schytheron/0a5c4756db62a1f43fc40226659c12cf/raw/71378ab9cede19e3f5bb33e948177a9fccfcc132/songs.xml and I genuinely don't even know where to begin. I am completely lost. Can this only be solved recursively or is there another way (because I have never tried doing recursion in Xquery)? Do you have any tips/strategies for solving this or any useful functions (I am very new to Xquery so I don't really know that many useful functions) I can use?

Thoughts? Ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to make things clear. I know that I can probably just do this manually for each element and their child elements with x amount of nested for-loops but I want to know if there is a way to make this dynamic so that it works with ANY XML database.

Comment: Seems like good job for XSLT: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ5. But I have only tried to consume the children of the root element as you described, I am not sure what you would want to happen for any child that has grandchildren, meaning the requirement to work with "any XML" seems underspecified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the limited use case of transforming the children of the root element as you want you can use some functions:

```
declare function local:transform($element as element()) as element() {
  element {name($element)} { 
    $element/node() ! local:attribute(.), 
    $element/@* ! local:element(.) 
  }
};

declare function local:attribute($node as node()) as attribute() {
  typeswitch ($node) 
     case element() return attribute {name($node)} {data($node) }
     case text() return attribute value { $node }
     default return ()

};

declare function local:element($att as attribute()) as element() {
  element {name($att)} { data($att) }
};

/*!element {name()} { *!local:transform(.) }
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4ki

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted :)